# How To Track Results of Vagrant Provisioning

Tags: ruby, bash, maven, vagrant

I'm using Vagrant to download and install some maven projects on a local RHEL VM. At the end of all of the maven installs I would like to be able to print out a list of each maven project that was installs and show whether each one failed or succeeded.

I suppose I could use some bash commands to capture the result with `"$?"`, then append that result to a file. Then after all the builds have finished, read the file and echo it out, but I was wondering if there were any less hacky solutions.

The solution I would prefer most is if I could just capture the `"$?"` from the result of the `mvn install` and kick it back out to the ruby code of the vagrantfile so that it could just be stored in a local variable, then displayed later. But I'm no expert at ruby, vagrant, or bash.

Comment: Why not add a task in your provisioning stack (Ansible, Chef, Puppet or otherwise, like Maven?) that sends out some kind of success trigger?

Comment: Could you just try to find the maven artifacts at the end of the provisioning ?

Comment: @tadman I'm not sure what you're suggesting. And even if I were, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @stalet I'm still pretty new to maven, but I'm not sure that solution would work for me. The maven projects that are being built are pulled down from a git repo regularly, and the artifact names may change from time to time. But maybe I've misunderstood something.